# CodedUI Build issue with TFS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

When I try to use the TFS 2015 Build process to deploy the Test Agent, I am receiving the following error:

> ‘The running command stopped because the preference variable
>   “ErrorActionPreference” or common parameter is set to Stop: Cannot
>   find path ‘C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\Ide\DTAExecutionHost.exe.config’ because it does not exist.’

I have Visual Studio Professional 2015 Edition installed on D drive and using TFS 2015 Test agent is getting installed on C drive.

As VS2015 Professional is installed on D driver so “`DTAExecutionHost.exe.config`” exists in D driver.

Is there any means by which we can configure Test Agent on D driver using TFS 2015 as I cannot uninstall VS2015 Professional on server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such setting to configure Test Agent on D Driver in step Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment.

Comment: As the issue occurs in Task 'ConfigureTestAgent', you can customize TestAgentConfiguration.ps1 if you are familiar with powershell script. Of course, the easiest way is installing VS 2015 in C driver.